# I would like a custom, resuable subview that can know about the model and lifecycle events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I come from an ASP.NET background so I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in iOS. Essentially, we have a design paradigm in our app where you can either have a single item in your model or multiple items. Depending on which one, different subviews are hidden/shown.

I have already created a custom subview that inherits from UIView which handles this with the help of a delegate to get some information from the ViewController. I have implemented it on multiple screens which works fine. However, the separate view controllers are duplicating a ton of code such as when to update the model, what to do when the model is updated, etc. Essentially, stuff that the view controller should do. It would be great to keep this code in one place as opposed to the different ViewControllers.

I know I can have my custom subview's class inherit from a UIViewController, but I also need the ability to have additional views above or below the reusable one. What are my options for this? In ASP.NET you can just create a user control which knows about the page lifecycle and can know about the model.

Comment: The common data structure for handling multiple items is an array, but did you know you can also think of a single item as being an array that only has one item? That negates the need for having duplicated logic and separate views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I know I can have my custom subview's class inherit from a UIViewController" -- no, you can't do this. A view can't inherit from UIViewController, and in Apple's MVC paradigm, a view shouldn't know anything about the model. Without knowing more about what you're doing, I would say one thing you can do is to make a base view controller class that your other controllers inherit from to cut down on the amount of duplicated code. Since the controller mediates between the model and the view, you should have the controller tell the view which of its subviews to show or hide, based on the model.